# 2D Dirac delta function: how to prove $\delta(ax, by) = \frac{1}{|ab|} \delta(x,y)$?

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let $\delta(x)$ be a Dirac-delta function. I am wondering how to prove the following:
\begin{align}
\delta(ax, by) = \frac{1}{|ab|} \delta(x,y)
\end{align}
Because of the definition (if I understand it correctly),
\begin{align}
\delta(ax, by) = \begin{cases}
\infty & \text{if $ax = 0,\ by=0,$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
If this is true, the scale of the argument should not influence the value of the delta function itself? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The best way to think about the Dirac delta is not to think of it as a function on numbers,  but to think of it as a functional taking in functions in a function space with an integral norm and outputting the value of that function at 0

Comment: That is not a good definition of $\delta.$ A close to correct definition is that 
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\delta(x,y)\,\phi(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\phi(0,0)$$
for all smooth functions $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: And to follow that up, consider the change of variables $t = ax$ and $s=by$, which gives $dx = dt/a$ and $dy=ds/b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the [dirac delta satisfies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Properties_in_n_dimensions):

1. case $ℝ→ℝ:\quad$  ${\displaystyle \delta (g(x))=\sum _{i}{\frac {\delta (x-x_{i})}{|g'(x_{i})|}}}$
2. case $ℝ^n→ℝ:\quad$  ${\displaystyle \int _{\mathbf {R} ^{n}}f(\mathbf {x} )\,\delta (g(\mathbf {x} ))\,d\mathbf {x} =\int _{g^{-1}(0)}{\frac {f(\mathbf {x} )}{|\mathbf {\nabla } g|}}\,d\sigma (\mathbf {x} )}$
3. case $ℝ^n→ℝ^n:\quad$  ${\displaystyle \int _{\mathbf {R} ^{n}}\delta (g(\mathbf {x} ))\,f(g(\mathbf {x} ))\left|\det g'(\mathbf {x} )\right|\,d\mathbf {x} =\int _{g(\mathbf {R} ^{n})}\delta (\mathbf {u} )f(\mathbf {u} )\,d\mathbf {u} }$

In Question [Expression for Dirac delta $\delta(xy)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4263808/99220), we had an instance of case (2). Your question is an instance of case (3), with $g(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\ y\end{smallmatrix}) = (\begin{smallmatrix}ax\\ by\end{smallmatrix})$:

$$\begin{aligned}
&& δ(g(x, y))|\det g'(x)| &= \delta(x, y)
\\&⟹& δ(ax, by) \Big|\det \pmatrix{a & 0 \\0 & b}\Big| &= \delta(x, y)
\\&⟹&δ(ax, by)|ab| &=  \delta(x, y)
\\&⟹&δ(ax, by) &= \frac{1}{|ab|}\delta(x, y)
\end{aligned}$$

For a proof of the theorem, see for example [Rigorous proof of the change of coordinates formula for Dirac's delta.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4166099/99220).

Answer (score 2):

**Simple answer:** this is a simple change of variable. Heuristically, since the Dirac delta $\delta$ is defined by its action on smooth functions $\varphi$ by
$$
\langle\delta,\varphi\rangle = \iint_{\Bbb R^2} \varphi(x,y)\,\delta(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y = \varphi(0,0),
$$
it follows by the change of variable $x'=a\,x$ and $y'=b\,y$ that
$$
\iint_{\Bbb R^2} \varphi(x,y)\,\delta(ax,by)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y = \frac{1}{|ab|}\iint_{\Bbb R^2} \varphi(\tfrac{x'}{a},\tfrac{y'}{a})\,\delta(x',y')\,\mathrm d x'\,\mathrm d y' = \frac{1}{|ab|} \,\varphi(0,0),
$$
or in other words $\langle\delta(ax,ay),\varphi\rangle = \frac{1}{|ab|}\langle\delta(x,y),\varphi\rangle$ for any $\varphi$, which implies $\delta(ax,ay) = \frac{1}{|ab|}\,\delta(x,y)$

---

**Digging a bit more**, now why can we do this change of variable in the integral? Actually this is because the composition of distributions is *defined* so that the change of variable formula works as if everything was done with classical integrals.