# Heaviside as distributional solution for transport PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives, transport-equation

I need to show that $H(x-ct)$ is a solution for the transport equation in the sense of distributions. I'm following the text *Partial Differential Equations* by Michael Shearer. Specifically, in Section 9.2.2, Example 7, Shearer has written:

> Consider a jump discontinuity $u(x,t) = u_-$ for $x < ct$ and $u(x,t)
> = u_+$ for $x > ct$ where $u_\pm$ and $c$ are constants $\dots$ We rewrite this function using the Heaviside function: $u(x,t) = (u_+ -
>  u_-)H(x - ct) + u_-$ $\dots$ Thus $\frac{du}{dt} = (u_+ - u_-) H'(x - ct) (-c)$.

My question is: How on earth does he obtain the mysterious $-c$ factor in his final expression for $\frac{du}{dt}$?

---

A little more background: It *looks* like Shearer is doing something like a chain rule, where differentiation of $H$ against the variable $t$ causes a factor of $-c$ to come out. In office hours, my professor essentially said not to use a chain rule. So I've tried all manner of integration and I just can't get it to work. Here's what one of my attempts looks like. In this attempt, I've tried to treat $u$ and $\phi$ as functions of the single variable $t$, since I am taking a partial derivative. I have no idea if this is the right approach, which is why I'm asking this question.

$$\begin{align*}
\langle u', \phi \rangle &= - \langle u, \phi' \rangle \\
&= -\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x - ct) \phi'(t) \; dt \\
&= \frac{1}{c} \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(z) \phi' \left(\frac{x}{c} - \frac{z}{c} \right) \; dz \\
&= \frac{1}{c} \int_{-\infty}^\infty H(z) \phi'\left(\frac{x}{c} - \frac{z}{c} \right) \; dz \\
&= \frac{1}{c} \int_0^\infty \phi' \left(\frac{x}{c} - \frac{z}{c} \right) \; dz \\
&= \left. \frac{1}{c} \cdot (-c) \cdot \phi\left(\frac{x}{c} - \frac{z}{c} \right) \right|_0^\infty \\
&= -\phi\left(\frac{x}{c}\right),
\end{align*}$$
so that $\phi' = -\delta(t - \frac{x}{c}) = \delta(x - ct)$. So...no factor of $-c$ appears. I've tried every thing I can think of. This is one of a dozen attempts. I'm just missing something. Please help!

Comment: Look at the change-of-variables for the Dirac delta $\delta(ax)=\frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x)$, for $a\neq 0$ (this is essentially a consequence of how changes of variables are defined for distributions). In your case, the error was in saying $\delta(t-\frac{x}{c})=\delta(x-ct)$, (where I assume your logic was that $t-\frac{x}{c}=0$ if and only if $x-ct=0$; but unfortunately that's not how the Dirac delta works). ALso, I'm not sure where your minus sign disappeared to.

Comment: i.e if you let $\rho_x(t)=\delta(x-ct)=\delta\left(-c\left(t-\frac{x}{c}\right)\right)$, meaning you think of $\rho_x$ as a distribution in the $t$-variable, then essentially by definition, $\langle \rho_x,\phi\rangle=\frac{1}{|-c|}\phi\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)$. As for why the definition is as such, see my answer to [Rigorous proof of the change of coordinates formula for Dirac's delta.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4166255/568204). Note that one can weaken the requirement in my answer of $\Phi$ being a diffeomorphism; for this see Hormander's PDE Vol 1 text, section 6.1.